# tenant-aware datasource in pentaho BI

Tags: pentaho

we have several clients(companies) each of them have separate database i.e companyA has databaseA,CompanyB has databaseB ...etc , so what i want to achieve is, in pentaho user console all of these companies use the same report but with a different datasoruce , for example 
CompanyA,CompanyB..etc would have access to a solution-folder called "Reports" this folder has
a list of reports e.g weeklySales_report so i want weeklySales_report to use CompanyA's database when the loged-in user is from companyA and use CompanyB's database when the logged-in user is from companyB,

i tried [this](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-6330) but i am getting this error

```
XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 67 in XML document from file [C:\pentaho2 
biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\system\pentahoObjects.spring.xml] is invalid; nes 
ed exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 67; columnNumber: 50 
 The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "property" must 
not contain the '<' character.
```

it is complaining about `<property name="datasourceNameFormat" value="<![CDATA[{0}-{1}]]>`

any ideas on what cause this error, or is there any other way to do this
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your way, but there is simply possibility to have dynamic jndi. You can have jndi in variable in xaction and can use it in xaction for distinguishing target database.

```
<inputs> 
<JNDDDI type="string"> 
  <sources> 
    <request>JNDDDI</request> 
  </sources>  
  <default-value><![CDATA[jndi_database1]]></default-value> 
</JNDDDI>
```

....

```
<action-definition> 
<component-name>SQLLookupRule</component-name>
<action-type>hourly</action-type>
<action-inputs> 
  <JNDDDI type="string"/>
</action-inputs>
<action-outputs> 
  <prepared_component type="sql-query"/> 
</action-outputs>
<component-definition> 
  <jndi>{JNDDDI}</jndi>  
  <query><![CDATA[select ...from ...]]></query>  
  <live><![CDATA[true]]></live> 
</component-definition>
```

And same thing if you use JasperReport Component.

Comment: Where can i get the documentation or wiki article on how to achieve this? i'm a newbie, i tried passing JNDI using Xaction but i guess one has to specify the SQL(select statement) in the xaction and feed the result of the query to the report, what if the reports are created using Metadata datasource? can i pass JNDI to the metadata using xaction?

Comment: How I can implements same things for CDE report ref click here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041600/pentaho-cde-report-change-data-according-to-user-login)